Why is an unsupported CSS value still overriding its fallback declarations?
I set up some CSS rules like:
.example {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgray;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-color: rgb(from var(--bg-color) r g b  / 0.5);
}

in the expectation that if a browser didn't understand the fairly new relative color syntax (or the fairly old but not ancient var() syntax) that my element would still be legible. But in older browsers I still end up with a transparent (getComputedStyle($0).backgroundColor === rgb(0,0,0,0)) background rather than the darker one I need for legibility.
Why are both of these true?

the browser doesn't understand the syntax (as evidenced by it not using the relative color)
the browser uses the rule anyway (as evidenced by the fallback rules going unused)

The CSS Values spec says re. "Partial implementations" that:

So that authors can exploit the forward-compatible parsing rules to assign fallback values, CSS renderers must treat as invalid (and ignore as appropriate) any at-rules, properties, property values, keywords, and other syntactic constructs for which they have no usable level of support. In particular, user agents must not selectively ignore unsupported component values and honor supported values in a single multi-value property declaration: if any value is considered invalid (as unsupported values must be), CSS requires that the entire declaration be ignored.

So my understanding is that a browser which doesn't understand or support my relative color syntax should be ignoring that entire declaration. So why isn't it using one of the earlier fallbacks?

What is the value of --bg-color in the example that you provided? Can you create a full reproducible example and specify the browser/version where the issue is present?

Thanks @SyndRain — that's a good catch! It is indeed the presence of the var() that makes the rule still apply when it otherwise wouldn't — I'll type up a longer answer because I think I found the spec why.

key here is CSS requires that the entire declaration be ignored. so all your CSS is ignored in that declaration as I interpret that sentence.

When using a valid var syntax and the syntax after substituting var is invalid, the value will be the same as using unset. This behavior is mentioned in the customer properties spec.
As per 3.1 Invalid variables:

A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if it contains a var() that references a custom property with the guaranteed-invalid value, as explained above, or if it uses a valid custom property, but the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is invalid. When this happens, the computed value is one of the following depending on the property’s type:

And under that section:

Either the property’s inherited value or its initial value depending on whether the property is inherited or not, respectively, as if the property’s value had been specified as the unset keyword.

With the reasoning of why it can't fall back to other declarations:

The invalid at computed-value time concept exists because variables can’t "fail early" like other syntax errors can, so by the time the user agent realizes a property value is invalid, it’s already thrown away the other cascaded values.

You can see this behavior in a simpler example, where the value results like unset:


body {
  color: green;
}

.example {
  --bg-red: red;
  color: blue;
  color: var(--bg-red) I am a invalid syntax;
}
<div class="example">test</div>




These are the only 3 ways I can think of to provide fallbacks for unsupported value syntax that includes the use of var(), ordered by how widely supported they are.

Make use of inheritance and set the fallback color in the parent, though this is not viable in your case since background-color is not inheritable, and has major drawback of the need to modify the parent element:



.parent {
  color: blue;
}

.example {
  --bg-color: red;
  color: rgb(from var(--bg-color) r g b / 0.5);
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="example">test</div>
</div>




Use feature query and replace the var in the supports-condition:



/*First Method*/
.example {
  --bg-color: red;
  background-color: darkgray;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
@supports (background-color: rgb(from red r g b / 0.5)) {
  .example {
    background-color: rgb(from var(--bg-color) r g b / 0.5);
  }
}
<div class="example">example 1</div>




Use custom @property to define the initial-value as the fallback value. This has the major drawback that the initail value must be hard coded:



@property --bg-relative {
  syntax: "<color>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: blue;
}

.example {
  --bg-color: red;
  --bg-relative: rgb(from var(--bg-color) r g b / 0.5);
  background-color: var(--bg-relative);
}
<div class="example">Example 2</div>




ah yes! I saw your initial comment and it led me to the same thing — thanks for fleshing it out into a complete answer

As another user pointed out in a (now-deleted?) comment on my question, this only happens when var() is used in the troublesome selector. If I try to use a relative color like rgb(from red r g b / 0.5) then my desired fallbacks are used.
I believe the answer lies in the spec re. invalid CSS variables which says:

A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if […] the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is invalid.

which results not in discarding the rule but rather it will behave:

[…] as if the property’s value had been specified as the unset keyword.

There's even a note that further reinforces this (after giving a very similar example to mine using background-color even ):

variables can’t "fail early" like other syntax errors can, so by the time the user agent realizes a property value is invalid, it’s already thrown away the other cascaded values.

I don't know why the user agent has to have necessarily thrown away the other values (that seems like an implementation or at least design choice?), but regardless it does explain it!
In short:
The presence of the var() means the browser uses the rule hoping it will resolve to something valid. But then if it turns out not to be valid in the end, it's too late to discard it and it resets the property instead.

you could try the following, some browsers do not accept var or rgb so it does not return anything (something transparent) this should work since you have a backup color.
.example {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgray; 
  background-color: var(--bg-color, darkgray); 
  background-color: rgb(from var(--bg-color) r g b / 0.5);
}

